# C# Date only for SQL linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a date field in SQL.  I am importing from Excel a field that has date with time. When I push the field into the DB it truncates the time without any problem. But when I try to validate rows using the datetime from the excel, I can't get to see if I have existing records with current date. I can't test with only Date

I am trying the following

```
DateTime orderdate = new DateTime(PDate.Year, PDate.Month, PDate.Day); ;
           
ExOrder = db.OrderDates.Where(x => x.Customer == Client & x.QDate == orderdate.Date).FirstOrDefault();
ordernum = ExOrder.OrderID;
```

`PDate` is being sent from the calling routine .

How can I get the orderdate to be only the date part?

Comment: `orderdate.Date` will consider the date part while checking the condition. Meaning, you're already doing that. Did I not get your question ? Can you please check in db, if `QDate` is really dropping the time. I doubt the time is there, which most probably is causing condition to be false.

Comment: The question and code make little sense without knowing what the Excel sheet contains, the classes and property types and the actual table types. A `datetime` field in a table isn't the same as a `date` field.

Comment: Hi, The db.OrderDates   QDate--oderdate.Date searches with the hour added so it never finds the record that exists with the year,date,month required

Comment: In that case, you need to do `x.QDate.Date` as well, instead of `x.QDate` in the condition. Or else make sure that hour part is not appending in db with QDate

Comment: I am reading the excel date column as DateTime.Parse(p[6].ToString() and the field in the DB is of type Date

The DateTime orderdate= new DateTime is giving me a date with time!!

Comment: As I said in DB QDate is just date no time !!

Answer (score 0):

You want to match by records by only date, then why not set both x.QDate and orderDate.Date to same date only format?
For example `db.OrderDates.Where(x => x.Customer == Client & x.QDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == orderdate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).FirstOrDefault();`